# Fatal error: 'continue' operator with non-constant operand is no longer supported

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm playing with some code and getting this error, the script should work with PHP 5.2+, I'm running 5.4.27.

Complete error,  `Fatal error: 'continue' operator with non-constant operand is no longer supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc.php on line 326`

Line 326,  `continue $scrape[$tracker] = self::set_error( new Exception( 'Tracker request timeout (' . $timeout . 's)' ), true );`

The complete code section,

```php
public function scrape ( $announce = null, $hash_info = null, $timeout = self::timeout ) {
    $packed_hash = urlencode( pack('H*', $hash_info ? $hash_info : $this->hash_info() ) );
    $handles = $scrape = array();
    if ( ! function_exists( 'curl_multi_init' ) )
        return self::set_error( new Exception( 'Install CURL with "curl_multi_init" enabled' ) );
    $curl = curl_multi_init();
    foreach ( (array) ($announce ? $announce : $this->announce()) as $tier )
        foreach ( (array) $tier as $tracker ) {
            $tracker = str_ireplace( array( 'udp://', '/announce', ':80/' ), array( 'http://', '/scrape', '/' ), $tracker );
            if ( isset( $handles[$tracker] ) )
                continue;
            $handles[$tracker] = curl_init( $tracker . '?info_hash=' . $packed_hash );
            curl_setopt( $handles[$tracker], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt( $handles[$tracker], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
            curl_multi_add_handle( $curl, $handles[$tracker] );
        }
    do {
        while ( ( $state = curl_multi_exec( $curl, $running ) ) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
        if( $state != CURLM_OK )
            continue;
        while ( $done = curl_multi_info_read( $curl ) ) {
            $info = curl_getinfo( $done['handle'] );
            $tracker = array_shift( explode( '?', $info['url'], 2 ) );
            if ( empty( $info['http_code'] ) )
                continue $scrape[$tracker] = self::set_error( new Exception( 'Tracker request timeout (' . $timeout . 's)' ), true );
            elseif ( $info['http_code'] != 200 )
                continue $scrape[$tracker] = self::set_error( new Exception( 'Tracker request failed (' . $info['http_code'] . ' code)' ), true );
            $stats = self::decode_data( curl_multi_getcontent( $done['handle']  ) );
            curl_multi_remove_handle( $curl, $done['handle'] );
            $scrape[$tracker] = empty( $stats['files'] ) ?
                self::set_error( new Exception( 'Empty scrape data' ), true ) :
                array_shift( $stats['files'] ) + ( empty( $stats['flags'] ) ? array() : $stats['flags'] );
        }
    } while ( $running );
    curl_multi_close( $curl );
    return $scrape;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`continue`](https://www.php.net/continue) is used to skip the rest of the current loop, and start with the next iteration. You can put a number behind it to tell how many loop levels out are to be skipped to the end of their iteration. If you don't specify a number, the defailt is 1.

But what you are putting behind `continue` not a number, but statements. Try to do the statements first, and then do `continue;`

So change:

```
if ( empty( $info['http_code'] ) )
    continue $scrape[$tracker] = self::set_error( new Exception( 'Tracker request timeout (' . $timeout . 's)' ), true );
elseif ( $info['http_code'] != 200 )
    continue $scrape[$tracker] = self::set_error( new Exception( 'Tracker request failed (' . $info['http_code'] . ' code)' ), true );
```

into:

```
if ( empty( $info['http_code'] ) ) {
    $scrape[$tracker] = self::set_error( new Exception( 'Tracker request timeout (' . $timeout . 's)' ), true );
    continue;
} elseif ( $info['http_code'] != 200 ) {
    $scrape[$tracker] = self::set_error( new Exception( 'Tracker request failed (' . $info['http_code'] . ' code)' ), true );
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Cool, that solved that part, I'm afraid I have got more similar issues, on line 671 shows same error, `continue self::set_error( new Exception( 'Files must be in the same folder: "' . $file . '" discarded' ) );`

Comment: Complete code `foreach ( $files as $i => $file ) {
if ( $path != array_intersect_assoc( $file_path = explode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file ), $path ) )
continue self::set_error( new Exception( 'Files must be in the same folder: "' . $file . '" discarded' ) );
if ( ! $handle = self::fopen( $file, $filesize = self::filesize( $file ) ) )
continue self::set_error( new Exception( 'Failed to open file: "' . $file . '" discarded' ) );
$pieces .= $this->pieces( $handle, $piece_length, $count == $i );
$info_files[] = array(
'length' => $filesize,
'path'  => array_diff( $file_path, $path )
);
}`

Comment: @D_Guy13 So what don't you understand? Do the statement that you have behind `continue` first, and then do `continue;`. And wrap those 2 lines in `{}` so they both are run within their `if`/`else`, since the `if`/`else` don't already have their own `{}`

Comment: Sure, Fixed it, thank you very much, something new to learn, appreciate your help.